# How to manage Windows firewall ports while running an MSI installation?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I have MSI Windows Installer files created by using the Wix Toolset and Wix files (*wxs). My requirement is that I need to open or close specific firewall ports while running the MSI installation.

Is there a way that it can be managed through specifications in the Wix files (*wxs) used to make the MSI installer?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [FirewallException](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/firewall/firewallexception.html) in WiX. You need to reference it inside your Visual Studio project. Find it at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixFirewallExtension.dll` for a standard installation of WiX.

As to the usage of the actual element:

- You can [find sample markup on github.com](https://github.com/search?p=3&q=FirewallException%20extension%3Awxs&type=Code).
- Bob Arnson's blog:
  http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/05/17/new-wix-feature-firewall-extension/

Basic usage step-by-step:

1. In Visual Studio project, add reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\bin\WixFirewallExtension.dll`

   - Right click your WiX project
   - Click "Add => Reference..." & browse to above path and double click file
2. Add to top level Wix element in your **`Project.wxs`** source file:  `xmlns:fire="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/FirewallExtension"`
3. Then add the markup. Something along these lines:

   ```
   <Component Feature="ProductFeature">

     <File Source="$(env.SystemRoot)\myexecutable.exe">
        <fire:FirewallException Id="FWX1" Name="Service" Port="[PORT]" Protocol="tcp" Scope="any" />
     </File>

   </Component>
   ```